# Error (Unexpected Token) using optional chaining syntax in Node 14/Vue2.js

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, optional-chaining

Optional chaining isn't working on my Vue.js (v2) project on Node 14.17.

```
const adventurer = {
  name: 'Alice',
  cat: {
    name: 'Dinah'
  }
};

const dogName = adventurer.dog?.name;
console.log(dogName);
// expected output: undefined

console.log(adventurer.someNonExistentMethod?.());
// expected output: undefined
```

I get the following error:

```
 ERROR  Failed to compile with 1 error                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              11:04:50
 error  in ./src/components/Thing.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js&

Module parse failed: Unexpected token (497:39)
File was processed with these loaders:
 * ./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js
 * ./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/index.js
You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.  
|             }
|         };
>         const dogName = adventurer.dog?.name;
|         console.log(dogName);
|         // expected output: undefined

 @ ./src/components/Thing.vue
 @ ./src/components/xx-thing.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js&
 @ ./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--0-0!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib??vue-loader-options!./src/views/Home.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js&
 @ ./src/views/Home.vue
 @ ./src/router.js
 @ ./src/main.js
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://172.16.8.210:8080/sockjs-node (webpack)/hot/dev-server.js ./src/main.js
```

I'm having a hunch it may be related to one of the below. I've installed Babel 7 as well, but perhaps the project still uses 6, as the Babel module name has apparently changed. But I don't know how to check, or how to switch it to 7, and even if that could be done without breaking the Vue project -- and perhaps it has nothing to do with that..

```
node -v
v14.17.6

npm ls webpack
webpack@4.46.0

npm ls @babel/core
7.15.5 (=latest)

npm ls @vue/cli-plugin-babel
4.5.13 (=latest)

npm ls @babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining
7.14.5 (=latest)

vue info

Environment Info:

  System:
    OS: Windows 10 10.0.18363
    CPU: (8) x64 Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-3770K CPU @ 3.50GHz
  Binaries:
    Node: 14.17.6 - C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.EXE
    Yarn: Not Found
    npm: 6.14.15 - C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm.CMD
  Browsers:
    Chrome: 92.0.4515.131
    Edge: Spartan (44.18362.1474.0)
  npmPackages:
    @vue/babel-helper-vue-jsx-merge-props:  1.2.1
    @vue/babel-helper-vue-transform-on:  1.0.2
    @vue/babel-plugin-jsx:  1.0.7
    @vue/babel-plugin-transform-vue-jsx:  1.2.1
    @vue/babel-preset-app:  4.5.13
    @vue/babel-preset-jsx:  1.2.4
    @vue/babel-sugar-composition-api-inject-h:  1.2.1
    @vue/babel-sugar-composition-api-render-instance:  1.2.4
    @vue/babel-sugar-functional-vue:  1.2.2
    @vue/babel-sugar-inject-h:  1.2.2
    @vue/babel-sugar-v-model:  1.2.3
    @vue/babel-sugar-v-on:  1.2.3
    @vue/cli-overlay:  3.12.1
    @vue/cli-plugin-babel: ^4.5.13 => 4.5.13
    @vue/cli-plugin-eslint: ^3.11.0 => 3.12.1
    @vue/cli-plugin-pwa: ^4.2.3 => 4.5.13
    @vue/cli-service: ^3.11.0 => 3.12.1
    @vue/cli-shared-utils:  3.12.1 (4.5.13)
    @vue/cli-upgrade: ^3.12.1 => 3.12.1
    @vue/component-compiler-utils:  3.2.2
    @vue/preload-webpack-plugin:  1.1.2
    @vue/web-component-wrapper:  1.3.0
    eslint-plugin-vue: ^7.4.0 => 7.17.0 (4.7.1)
    vue: ^2.6.10 => 2.6.14
    vue-cli-plugin-vuetify: ^0.6.3 => 0.6.3
    vue-eslint-parser:  7.11.0 (2.0.3)
    vue-force-next-tick: ^1.1.0 => 1.1.0
    vue-head: ^2.2.0 => 2.2.0
    vue-hot-reload-api:  2.3.4
    vue-loader:  15.9.8
    vue-meta: ^2.3.2 => 2.4.0
    vue-router: ^3.0.3 => 3.5.2
    vue-sse: ^1.0.2 => 1.1.1
    vue-style-loader:  4.1.3
    vue-template-compiler: ^2.6.10 => 2.6.14
    vue-template-es2015-compiler:  1.9.1
    vue-the-mask:  0.11.1
    vuedraggable:  2.24.3
    vuetify: ^2.5.8 => 2.5.8
    vuetify-form-base: ^0.3.2 => 0.3.3
    vuetify-loader: ^1.4.3 => 1.7.3
  npmGlobalPackages:
    @vue/cli: Not Found
```

I've also tried adding `plugins: ["@babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining"],` to babel.config.js

I've also tried to uninstall babel 6, but the npm uninstaller fails to actually uninstall it.

Could have a similar root cause, (unfortunately unresolved):
[Optional chaining not working in Node 14 LTS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68948480/optional-chaining-not-working-in-node-14-lts)

Comment: We're using Node.js 14 with a Vite.js build stack in our project, and we don't have any issues with optional chaining.

Comment: This might be because Vue3 allegedly has out-of-the-box support for optional chaining, and Vite isn't available for Vue2.. I'm currently waiting on Vuetify to be ready for Vue3 to move on..

Comment: We're not using Vue at all. We just use Vite vanilla.

Comment: Little late here, but ran into a similar issue, and while looking into it noticed that Vue 2 is [using webpack 4](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/blob/2.6/package.json#L140). And Webpack 4 is [using Acorn 6](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/blob/webpack-4/package.json#L12). Wheras support for optional chaining wasn't implemented into Acorn until [version 7.2.0](https://github.com/acornjs/acorn/releases/tag/7.2.0). So I guess the only solution to this would be, as you mentioned, Babel.

Answer (score 3):

#### Cause

This is because Vue 2 is [using webpack 4](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/blob/2.6/package.json#L140). And Webpack 4 is [using Acorn 6](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/blob/webpack-4/package.json#L12). Wheras support for optional chaining wasn't implemented into Acorn until [version 7.2.0](https://github.com/acornjs/acorn/releases/tag/7.2.0).

#### Solution

To use optional chaining, and other newer features, you will need to use Babel. This feature is available in [`@babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining`](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-proposal-optional-chaining), which is also included in the [ECMA-262](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-optional-chains) / [`@babel/preset-env`](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-preset-env), or specificially for Vue apps: just `@vue/app`.

If you've not already done so, you'll need `vue add @vue/cli-plugin-babel`. Then just update your Babel config with a valid preset, e.g.

```json
"babel": {
  "presets": [
    "@vue/app"
  ]
}
```

A more detailed guide, can be found [here](https://markus.oberlehner.net/blog/setting-up-a-vue-project-with-webpack-4-and-babel-7/).

Restart the dev server/ rebuild the app, and optional chaining should now work :)

Comment: I had to remove @vue/cli-plugin-babel/preset in order to add @vue/app. However, it still won't work ("Unexpected token"), but I suspect this has something to do with my tsconfig. I've been poking at it for a while now, but can't get it to run. If all fails I'll wait for Vue3, which is around the corner for me now.. My original babel.config.js:

module.exports = {
  presets: [
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel/preset",
    "@babel/preset-env",
  ],
  "plugins": ["@babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining"],
}